# Multiplying variables with different bases and different exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm stuck.  Helping kid with alg II and the instructions say to simplify the expression into one radical.  $$\sqrt{10} \cdot \sqrt[4]{3}$$
I know how to do it with same base, or same exponent, but ten to the 1/2 times 3 to the 1/4?  Am I just overthinking this?  I can't see it.

Comment: First step, $(\sqrt[4]{100})(\sqrt[4]{3})$.  In general, if dealing with $x^{a/b}y^{c/d}$, first step is to bring $a/b$ and $c/d$ to a common denominator.

Answer (score 0):

Without the square root signs (in the other answers since deleted) it might be easier to see your way to the solution.

$$
10^{\frac{1}{2}} 3^{\frac{1}{4}} = 
10^{\frac{2}{4}} 3^{\frac{1}{4}} =
(10^2 \times 3)^{\frac{1}{4}} = 300^{\frac{1}{4}}
$$

This method will work for $x^ay^b$ when $a$ and $b$ are rational - just write the exponents using their least common denominator.

(I started this answer several hours ago before I saw @AndreNicolas comment.)

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to realize that $\sqrt{10}$ can be rewritten as $\sqrt[4]{100}$.  There are at least two ways to make this connection:

- You could recognize that $10 = \sqrt{100}$, so $\sqrt{10}=\sqrt{\sqrt{100}}$.
- You could write $\sqrt{10}$ as $10^{1/2}$, and then rewrite $1/2$ as $2/4$, so we have $10^{2/4} = (10^2)^{1/4}$.